# Changing value of a value in a dictionary within a list within a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a json like:

```
pd = {
    "RP": [
        {
        "Name": "PD",
        "Value": "qwe"
        },
        {
        "Name": "qwe",
        "Value": "change"
        }
    ],
    "RFN": [
        "All"
    ],
    "RIT": [
        {
        "ID": "All",
        "IDT": "All"
        }
    ]
    }
```

I am trying to change the value `change` to `changed`. This is a dictionary within a list which is within another dictionary. Is there a better/ more efficient/pythonic way to do this than what I did below:

```
for key, value in pd.items():
    ls = pd[key]
    for d in ls:
        if type(d) == dict:
            for k,v in d.items():
                if v == 'change':
                   pd[key][ls.index(d)][k] = "changed"
```

This seems pretty inefficient due to the amount of times I am parsing through the data.

Comment: Question, why do you need to iterate through each key, when only "RP" seems to contain the Name and Value keys in its list of dicts.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal The key 'RP' could change in the future, so I tried to keep it as dynamic as possible. The only control I have is over the value `change`

Comment: So all instances of the value "change", irrespective of where they are, need to be replaced by "changed"?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal yes

Comment: And, are these dicts/dict too large to handle or usually small in size

Comment: @AkshaySehgal well, not huge, but to the point where it could be a performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String replacement could work if you don't want to write depth/breadth-first search.

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(json.dumps(pd).replace('"Value": "change"', '"Value": "changed"'))
{'RP': [{'Name': 'PD', 'Value': 'qwe'}, {'Name': 'qwe', 'Value': 'changed'}],
 'RFN': ['All'],
 'RIT': [{'ID': 'All', 'IDT': 'All'}]}
```